# Rails & Youtube API: Issues loading iframe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to implement the Youtube Iframe API into my Rails app. I'm trying to replicate the exact example on the [Youtube Iframe API instructions page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

1. Created a yt_player.js file:

   ```
   $(function() {

      alert('this gets called')

      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
         var tag = document.createElement('script');

     tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
     var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

     // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
     //    after the API code downloads.
     var player;
     function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
       alert('this does not get called')
       player = new YT.Player('player-wrapper', {
         height: '390',
         width: '640',
         videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
         events: {
           'onReady': onPlayerReady,
           'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
         }
       });
     }
     // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
     function onPlayerReady(event) {
       event.target.playVideo();
     }

     // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
     //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
     //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
     var done = false;
     function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
       if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
         setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
         done = true;
       }
     }
     function stopVideo() {
       player.stopVideo();
     }
   });
   ```

And my view:

```
<div id="player-wrapper"></div>
```

I was expecting this to work but no video is being loaded. No errors showing in console.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm pretty sure your `window.player` and `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` are `undefined` when you check in the browser console.

The reason is the way `youtube iframe api` work, those above variables must be defined globally.

Let check this [document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

They say:

> The onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function will execute as soon as the player API code downloads. This portion of the code defines a **global variable**, player, which refers to the video player you are embedding, and the function then constructs the video player object.

So the changes will be: (define youtube variables and callbacks globally)

```
// Your current code
window.player = null; // <-- change here
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {  // <-- change here
  alert('this does not get called')
  player = new YT.Player('player-wrapper', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

window.onPlayerReady = function(event) {  // <-- change here
  event.target.playVideo();
}

window.done = false;  // <-- change here
window.onPlayerStateChange = function(event) {  // <-- change here
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
    done = true;
  }
}
window.stopVideo = function() {  // <-- change here
  player.stopVideo();
}
```